# How to delete item from collection view?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I try to remove an item from a collection view based on a user's choice in an alert.

I have the following code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let person = people[indexPath.item]

    let questionController = UIAlertController(title: "What u wanna do?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    questionController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rename person", style: .Default, handler: {

        (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Rename person", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)

        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] _ in
            let newName = ac.textFields![0] as! UITextField
            person.name = newName.text

            self.collectionView.reloadData() })

        self.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))

    questionController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Person", style: .Default, handler: {

        (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        println("hello world")
        self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.item])
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    }))

    presentViewController(questionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

"hello world" works okay but the app crashes when I press "Delete Person".

The console output is

```
hello world
2015-07-18 13:40:14.628 Project10[15888:1274436] -[__NSCFNumber section]:         unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003
2015-07-18 13:40:14.636 Project10[15888:1274436] *** Terminating app due to    uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber    section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should change

```
self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.item])
```

to

```
self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
```

[`deleteItemsAtIndexPaths`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:) expects an array of `NSIndexPath`s, not an array of numbers.

Besides that, if you call `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` you don't need a call to `reloadData` - this will even prevent any animation from happening.

Don't forget to update your data source - the person has to be removed from the `people` array.

```
people.removeAtIndex(indexPath.item)
```

Do this *before* calling `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths`.

Comment: didnt help
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Don't forget to update your data source - the person has to be removed from the `people` array.

Comment: sorry, im new in swift - how to update data source ?

Comment: i added self.people.removeAtIndex(indexPath.item) after the self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath]) but it still crashes with same error

Comment: You need to do it *before*. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Your last line saved me a bunch of headache! Thanks a lot!