# How to remove model class data in the array in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Here I am trying to remove particular index data when delete button pressed from the array which saved using model class can anyone help me to remove data from the array and to not display in collection view ?

Here I had tried this code

Here I had declared like this  as array

```
var cartItemsModel = [CartItems]()
```

Below is my delete button action

```
 @objc func deleteAction(sender : UIButton){
        let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint(), to: cartCollectionView)
        let indexPath = cartCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: buttonPosition)
        self.deleteIndexPath = indexPath
        self.Index = sender.tag
        let obj = cartItemsModel[(indexPath?.row)!]
        self.cartItemsModel.remove(at: (indexPath?.row)!)
        self.itemId = obj.itemID
        self.price = obj.price
        //        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        let attribute = RappleActivityIndicatorView.attribute(style: .apple, tintColor: .white, screenBG: .darkGray, progressBG: .black, progressBarBG: .orange, progreeBarFill: .red, thickness: 4)
        RappleActivityIndicatorView.startAnimatingWithLabel("Processing...", attributes: attribute)
        //        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        if loginCheck == 1 {
            let customerDeleteAPI = "\(domainName)/V1/carts/mine/items/\(itemId!)/"
            customerItemsDeleteDownloadJsonWithURL(customerItemsAPI: customerDeleteAPI)
        }else {
            let deleteApi = "\(domainName)/en/V1/guest-carts/\(self.guestQuoteId!)/items/\(itemId!)/"
            deleteItemsDownloadJsonWithURL(deleteItemsAPI: deleteApi)
        }
    }
```

Below is after calling delete api depending on response I was trying to remove the array which selected and the code is

```
self.cartItemsModel.remove(at: (self.deleteIndexPath?.row)!)
```

and I tried another code also shown below

```
self.cartItemsModel.remove(at: self.Index!)
```

Comment: reload your collectionview after delete with .reloadData()

Comment: could you elaborate what you are trying to do? and about the issue, you are getting

Comment: it crashes at this line `self.cartItemsModel.remove(at: (self.deleteIndexPath?.row)!)` @koropok

Comment: I was just removing the array data locally and to reload collection instead of calling cart items api @ram880

Comment: Are you saying you are doing `self.cartItemsModel.remove` _again_ after calling the api? You are already removing the item in the code you showed us here.

Comment: you can this method for deleting self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexpaths]) to delete. Then remove from array like  self.cartItemsModel.remove(at: indexpath.item) . and make sure api call success before you proceed to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below-tagged answer. It will solve your problem.

[delete item from collection view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31490371/1496321)

But after your successful API call uses these methods.

Also, remove the item from the array first before `collectionView.deleteItems(at: [])`